# How to get the actual acceleration via CMMotionManager in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I am getting x,y and z device acceleration using **startDeviceMotionUpdates()**, and reading the **userAcceleration** data structure with a Timer.  Apple documentation states

> The total acceleration of the device is equal to gravity plus the acceleration the user imparts to the device.

The values that I am getting even if I jerk the phone around are at the most 5.7nnnn on the X axis for example.  Now, if the gravity acceleration is 9.81 m/sec squared, what does the value 5.7nnnn represent in m/sec squared?  That is, how do I get the actual m/sec squared value from the raw axis values that **userAcceleration** gives?  How does one interpret the difference between acceleration and deceleration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CoreMotion (CM) outputs acceleration in g's. So, you'd need to multiply the values with ~9.81 m/s^2.

Also, CM acceleration readings are reversed compared to a more conventional accelerometer; i.e., when the device is stationary on a table, CM measures approximately -1.0 on the z axis, while a conventional accelerometer would measure approximately 9.81 m/s^2 (note that the former value is negative, while the latter is positive). So, if you multiply the CM readings with -9.81, you would get intuitive results: a positive value along an axis would mean acceleration and a negative value would mean deceleration.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a great answer.  I don't understand though, why the documentation says "gravity PLUS the acceleration"..  It's strange.

Comment: The acceleration measured on the device really consists of gravity + acceleration imparted by the user. The accelerometer hardware itself has no way of distinguishing between these two components. To report `userAcceleration`, CM uses other sensors (such as gyroscope), i.e. performs sensor fusion, to first determine the 3D orientation of the device, then separate gravity and user acceleration components using this orientation. So `userAcceleration` is really `total acceleration - gravity`.